# Dawn - What happens after Ceres?

Tags: nasa, asteroid, mission-design, asteroid-belt, dawn-mission

Soon, the Dawn spacecraft will reach and orbit Ceres. Any ideas about what will happen after this work?

Comment: I found this question that pretty much answers mine.. Apologies for the dupe.. http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/540/does-the-dawn-spacecraft-have-the-potential-for-an-extended-mission?rq=1

Comment: Dupes on themselves aren't such a problem. While we should try not to have them, they can expose other problems with site contents (e.g. the question of which yours is a duplicate, could use better tagging so it's easier to find... I've amended that now), and in terms of SEO and search facility on the site, they do make the questions they later point to easier to find. Don't worry about it, it's still a legit question for which the answer isn't readily available and apparent. And thanks for pointing out it's a dupe yourself!